# Google Places Autocomplete - Types: Geocode, Address, Establishment - Not Working Properly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to set the types in google places autocomplete and it's getting me crazy!

I want my users to be able to filter there search by typing the address or a establishment they are looking for, but for some reason it's not working properly.

**Code I am using:**

```
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=[my_api_key]"></script>
<script>
    var searchInputStart = 'start_address';
    start_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(searchInputStart)), {
        types: ['geocode'],
        types: ['address'],
        types: ['establishment']
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(start_address, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place_start = start_address.getPlace();
        document.getElementById('loc_lat_start').value = place_start.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('loc_long_start').value = place_start.geometry.location.lng();
        //get_directions to address
        set_route();
    });
</script>
```

> If I take out --> types: [address] --> it shows the establishments correct, but not the addresses.
>
> If I take out --> types: [establishement] --> it shows the addresses correct, but not the establishements.

How can my users filter places correctly from typing an address or establishment?

Can anyone help me please? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google Maps API documentation you can set only one type in place autocomplete options.

> **types** `Array<string>`: The types of predictions to be returned. For a list of supported types, see the developer's guide. If nothing is specified, all types are returned. **In general only a single type is allowed.** The exception is that you can safely mix the 'geocode' and 'establishment' types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no types.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions

That means that you can use

```
start_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById(searchInputStart), 
    {
        types: ['address']
    }
);
```

or

```
start_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById(searchInputStart), 
    {
        types: ['geocode', 'establishment']
    }
);
```

but not all of them in the same options object.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Hi xomena. Thank you very much for helping me. Your help clarified me. In my situation, it's better not to use any types. I only need to get the addresses from my users.